# basic auth Codeceptjs with Appium

Tags: authentication, appium, basic-authentication, codeceptjs

having a bit of headache getting past basic auth for our uat environments, we have switched to using Appium and I am trying to configure Codeceptjs to allow me to pass through credentials.

My current config looks like :-

```
 exports.config = {
  output: './output',
  helpers: {
    Appium: {
      path: '/wd/hub',
      port: 4723,
      platform: 'Android',
      browserName: 'Chrome',
      url: 'https://test.co.uk/',
      basicAuth: {username: 'user', password: 'pass'},
      show: true,
```

I have looked through the Codeceptjs docs and this should pass my credentials through, does Appium work differently? All I am doin is hitting a website on a mobile, any help would be gratelly appreciated.

Forgot to mention I am testing on Android/chrome, also reults at the momemnt the username/password posted in the url obviously result site can not be reached.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, seems like having special characters in the username/password, was causing the problem, now resolved.